# Prove $\forall n\geq 2,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(n+1)\mid(n^3+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

**Question**: Prove $\forall n\geq 2,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(n+1)\mid(n^3+1)$

---

I know that it is possible to solve by factoring $n^3+1$ and showing that $n+1$ is a multiple, but I would like to show this via induction.

**Attempt**: Using induction:

Let $n=2:3\mid 9$, so true for $n=2$

(1) Assume true for $n=k:(k+1)\mid(k^3+1)$, so $(k+1)r=k^3+1$ for some $r\in\mathbb{Z}$

(2) Let $n=k+1:(k+2)\mid(k+1)^3+1$, so $(k+2)s=(k+1)^3+1$ for some $s\in\mathbb{Z}$

From (2) we have $(k+1)s+s=(k+1)^3+1$, subbing (1) into (2), I get $k^3+1+s=(k+1)^3+1$

Therefore $k^3+s=(k+1)^3$.

Setting $s=3k^2+3k+1$, this holds.

Where am I going wrong, is the proof valid, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your proof you used the assumption $r=s$, which holds iff $k=0$ or $k=-2$.

Comment: You seem to be *using* (2), when what you're meant to do is *deduce* (2). But I doubt induction is going to work (without using the factorization of $n^3+1$, perhaps in some hidden way).

Comment: OK, thanks, was wondering if it was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just to factorise $n^3+1,$

giving: $n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$

so $(n+1)$ divides $n^3+1$ as required.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer here and the fact that you specifically state in your OP that you're seeking a solution that doesn't involve factorisation.

Comment: Asked this a while back, this is how I solved it in case anyone wanted the answer.

Comment: If you don't want perform facterisation explicitly, you can just check that $n^3+1$ is $0$ when $n=-1$.